# What is the difference between using parenthesis and not using parenthesis in a method in Python

Tags: python, parentheses

```
d=dict(a=1)
```

What is the difference between the following two?

```
d.clear
d.clear()
```

Why can't the first clear the dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

Using parenthesis calls the function where as not using them creates a reference to that function.

See below:

```
>>> def t():
...     return "Hi"
...
>>> a = t
>>> a
<function t at 0x01BECA70>
>>> a = t()
>>> a
'Hi'
>>>
```

Here is a good link to explain further: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html (scroll down to the "defining functions" part).

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't actually call the function. In Python, you can use functions as values, so you can assign a function to a new variable like this:

```
def timeTen(n):
    return n * 10

fn = timesTen
```

then you can call it later:

```
print(fn(5))   # 50
```

Functions are just values that just happen to have a certain property (that you can call them).

Answer (score 1):

With `()` you execute function. Without `()` you get reference to function - and you can assign this to variable and execute later with new name.

```
new_d = d.clear # assign

new_d() # execute
```

**BTW:** in Ruby and Perl you can call function without parenthesis.